# Materialize CSS Autocomplete sorting based on a specific word

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, materialize

I'm using [Materialize CSS Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) for my Google Apps Script with the data populated form my Google Contacts. I would like to be able to sort the order in which the contacts appear based on a specific word in their names. For example, lets say I have the following contacts:

- Jason Garcia
- Jonathan Jackson **Mobile**
- Monica Stokes
- Amy Wang **Mobile**
- Aaron Bridges

I would like the contacts which contain the word **Mobile** to appear on top of the list and the rest in the alphabetical order:

- Amy Wang **Mobile**
- Jonathan Jackson **Mobile**
- Aaron Bridges
- Jason Garcia
- Monica Stokes

To do that, I've been trying to use the sortFunction from the Materialize CSS documentation but with no success. How could I achieve something like that?

Comment: Restructure your array. Create an new array with the keyword you need Remove the element with key word from original array.  and using unshift or splice or concur to merge two array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array by checking if it contains the term "mobile", see below. This returns first all which do contain "mobile" and then all others.

```
const arr = ["Tom Mobile", "Sam", "Jess Mobile"]
arr.sort( (el1) => {
   if(el1.search(/mobile/gi) == -1) return 1
   return -1
}))
```

But that is for array and you do not need arrays, therefore that answer was general and not specific. Therefore I did a quick demo of what you actually wanted:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const options = {
        data : {
        "Tom mobile" : null,
        "Thomas" : null,
        "Tim mobile" : null
      },
      sortFunction : sortBy
    }
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);
  });
  
  // Sort function for sorting autocomplete results
  // prioritize if text contains mobile
  function sortBy(a, b) {    
    return  b.indexOf("mobile") - a.indexOf("mobile");
  }
```

Reference

- [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [string.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please specify where exacltly I should put this code? Here is a basic Materialize CSS Autocomplete initialization code: `$(document).ready(function(){$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({data: {"Tom Mobile": null,"Sam": null,"Jess Mobile": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'},});});`. As far as I understand, the sorting is difined by a Materialize sortFunction, but a simple copy/paste of your code into the sortFunction didn't do the trick.

Comment: Hi Michael, please see above, I've updated the answer to fit your requirements. If it works then mark it as done.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately your updated code didn´t work for me either - I guess it has something to do with the way [Materialize uses the sortFunction](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5644)

Comment: Weird, I tried and tested it. One thing may be that in my example I am using "mobile" and in your example you are using "Mobile". Since `indexOf()` is case-sensitive, I suggest you try again my modifying your code to fit your case. This means that you should try to change "mobile" to "Mobile" in the `sortBy()` above.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that I had some non English characters in my full data, which messed up the sort function.